# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC endpoint routing and localization by route

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I started messing with endpoint routing and url translation but i think i'm missing somthing.

My solution is [here](https://github.com/bonioloa/Core3LocalizationAndRouteTranslation)

I started from the example in [this blog post](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/)

writing urls in address bar works as expected but I noticed that anchor tag don't generate url at all.

Layout sample

```
     @{ 
         Dictionary<string, string> routePol = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         routePol.Add("language", "pl");
         routePol.Add("controller", "Home");
         routePol.Add("action", "Index");
    }
    <a asp-all-route-data="routePol">Poland</a>
```

should generate

```
<a href="test/pl/Home/Index">Poland<a>
```

result

```
<a href >Poland<a>
```

Main endpoint

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>(
                    "{language=pl}/{controller=orders}/{action=list}");
            });
```

I don't understand what is wrong. I read around that with endpoint routing, anchor tag does not generate urls when the provided values generate a not existing route, but the route above should be valid.

If it's possible, is there a way to debug how route is validated or log errors?

**EDIT:** problem now solved, thanks to Rena.
I updated [my solution](https://github.com/bonioloa/Core3LocalizationAndRouteTranslation) with fixes and I added a useful component for culture change using route value, hope that will be useful to everyone that will stumble in same problems as me.

Comment: For debug how route is validated or log errors,you could debug with the source code to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog show us how to translate the url when you send request.But in your case,you just want to render url,it should add route template to match it.

Here is a smiple workaround like below:

1.View:

```
@{
Dictionary<string, string> routePol = new Dictionary<string, string>();
routePol.Add("language", "pl");
routePol.Add("controller", "zamowienia");
routePol.Add("action", "lista");    
}
@*controler name and action name should be the key name in TranslationDatabase 
not the value name.*@
<a asp-all-route-data="routePol">Poland</a>
```

2.Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{language=pl}/{controller=orders}/{action=list}");
            endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>(
                "{language=pl}/{controller=orders}/{action=list}");

        });
```

It would generate the url:`/pl/zamowienia/lista` and when you click the link,it would get into `orders/list` action

Comment: still does not work. Updated solution with main language as "en" and main endpoint with language "en". I left only one alternative language, and updated links in layout. Href fields still empty on all links.

Comment: Sorry for I have missed something(Startup.cs) to post,please check my answer.

Comment: my god you are right, the problem was the default route. With this addition i confirm that route building works even without using translated route for other languages apart from main one. I.E. this works `@{ 
         Dictionary<string, string> routeItCtrlAct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         routeItCtrlAct.Add("language", "it");
         routeItCtrlAct.Add("controller", "home");
         routeItCtrlAct.Add("action", "index");
    }
    <a asp-all-route-data="routeItCtrlAct">Indice italiano (route builded with real controller-action)</a>`

Comment: @Rena @albe Hey guys, I have this setup for routing:

`endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
 name: "solver_cultured",
 pattern: "{culture=en}/solve/{*equation}",
 defaults: new { Controller = "Solve", action = "SolveOne" });`

But I can't make it work to translate the route for example to DE:

`{culture=de}/berechnung/{*equation}`

Comment: what {*equation} means in your routing? the asterisk has some special meaning?

Comment: @albe `{*equation}` is any math string which is passed to the route.

The question is can I use this routing approach:

`endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
 name: "solver_cultured",
 pattern: "{culture=en}/{controller=solve}/{*equation}",
 defaults: new { action = "SolveOne" }
);`

Along with:

`endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{culture=en}/{controller=solve}/{*equation}");`

???

Comment: imho this only works with a explicit route pattern; if you want to translate also a querystring, it may be possible, but you have to explicitly map every possible route parameters (also querystring parameters) in translation transformer class as keys and then provide a translation dictionary for them. Keep a simple lang/controller/action route and then play with querystring parameters